# How to trigger a Macro by ONLY selecting any cell in the row directly below a table (ListObject)

Tags: excel, vba, listobject

I currently have the code below which triggers my `Addrecordtotable` when you click on/select any cell in in the row below the Table (the Named Range in my code: "Table2") *but also* any cell *in* the table.

How can I instead restrict the code to trigger the macro when you click on/select any cell *only* in the row *directly below* the ListObject/table?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table2").Offset(1)) Is Nothing Then
            Call Addrecordtotable
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If I am correct, you move the complete "Table2" range down by one row. You will have to trim it to one row, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `Range("Table2").Offset(1)` offsets the range of the entire table. So the range is now the size of the tabele but one row down.

What you actually need to to is to go down the amount of rows that the table has (so the range **begins** in the row below the table, and then resize it to one row.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("Table2").Offset(RowOffset:=Me.Range("Table2").Rows.Count).Resize(RowSize:=1)) Is Nothing Then
            Call Addrecordtotable
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Also note that instead of `Selection` you should use `Target` here. And you need to use `CountLarge` instead of `Count` because otherwise you get an overflow error if you select all cells of the worksheet.